# Best Data Structure for strings

Tags: java, search

I want a make an app for a Bible. But I'm wondering how to store the data so searching will be fast. I'm think of 2D arrays but that seems tasking and slow.

Thanks.

Comment: `Map<String, String>` maybe?

Comment: Searching is a solved problem.  You don't need your own data structure unless you are doing something extraordinarily trivial or if you want to learn-by-doing.  If you are writing a serious Java application, link in Lucene or a similar library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Map<String, String>` as Reimeus suggested.

You could also try a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This is a data structure allows predictive searching. That is, you type in part of a word and it can predict how you might finish the word.

A [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAWG) would probably be a better option for something as large as the Bible, but its a bit more complex than a trie.

Comment: *"something as large as the Bible"*? Really? (FWIW google returns 3.6 million characters)

Comment: I guess its not google's English corpus but either way a DAWG would probably be more space efficient.